# OneNote "Waiting for update"

Tags: sync, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2016

One of my OneNote notebooks keeps saying `Waiting for update`, while all the others work fine. This problematic one is indeed the notebook with the largest content. Can I ask how to remove this error message?

[image]

This [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_onenote-mso_windows8-mso_365hp/onenote-sync-problem-waiting-for-update/8189e932-a6b3-4d70-bc61-71f8cbe33006) suggests "Misplaced Sections popped up", but I could not see any "Misplaced Sections".

Answer (score 0):

1. SUGGESTED SOLUTION: MISPLACED SECTIONS -

For me, this appears only after you try to close the malfunctioning notebook. The instructions in that link are a bit confusing. Close notebook first → Misplaced sections appear →  Delete them (or copy to elsewhere) → re-open notebook → all good.

This did not resolve the problem for me.

2. MY SOLUTION: EMPTY RECYCLE BIN -

Close the notebook (right click notebook name → "Close This Notebook") → Delete the misplaced sections (same as suggested solution above) → Navigate to the folder where your notebook is stored (in my case, a shared network folder) → Open the notebook folder → Open the sub-folder "OneNote_RecycleBin" → Delete all files therein → re-open notebook → all good.